# Is there a convention for project-local NuGet Repositories?

Tags: .net, nuget, dependency-management

I've nearly finished migrating a large solution to use NuGet for dependencies. Prior to this, the project simply had a *Lib* directory with all binary dependencies in sub-directories within it. There are, however, a few dependencies that aren't available in the official NuGet feed. Therefore, I have a few options:

1. Add them to the official NuGet feed.
2. Keep the existing *Lib* directory with any non-NuGet binaries within it.
3. Create a project-local NuGet feed that contains only those packages that aren't available in the official feed.

I don't like #1 because it implies I'll be taking on responsibility for keeping the packages up-to-date. I don't like #2 because it's messy having two mechanisms for managing dependencies within the one solution.

Therefore, I'm leaning towards #3, but cannot find any documentation on conventions. I understand how to create the local feed, how to tell Visual Studio about it et cetera. What I can't find is whether there is a convention around the naming of the directory containing the local feed and anything else this approach may entail. Does anyone know what the standard practice is?

Comment: I don't think there is any documentation for this specific scenario. You could instead setup a local NuGet server on your network if you go with a modified version of case 3. Since we've built [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget), we use that to handle both 3rd-party libraries in other projects we have by creating a NuGet package and publishing to our own repository to avoid polluting the official feed. Since ProGet can connect with the official feed to download packages, just point VS at the ProGet feed and you're done - it will transparently give you download access to the official packages.

Answer (score 2):

What you're missing is Option #4 - set up a private NuGet repository. This is the standard practice for solving this problem.

There are several private NuGet servers available, including one that my company ([Inedo](http://inedo.com)):

- Nuget.Server - the free/open source one; very limited
- ProGet - for behind the firewall; free version available
- MyGet - hosted service; free version available
- Artifactory - multi-platform (Java, etc)

The whole point of a "dependency manager" (i.e. NuGet) is to manage dependencies across projects, so there's really no point in having a "project-local repository" -- that's effectively just a really over-complicated "lib" folder.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense...kind of. Thing is, option #3 *is* a private NuGet repo - so private that only my project can see it :) Any less private than that yields a certain responsibility to keep the server (and packages) maintained. Suppose, for example, that a new version of one of my packages comes out that I don't want but others do - there might be an expectation that I update the repo. Same thing when the server has issues. *shrugs* I've gone with project-level repo for now - will be easy to move elsewhere should I feel the need.

Comment: Well, option #3 is actually just an overly-complicated way of having a "lib" folder. It adds all the complexity with none of the benefits. A private repo solves all of these problems, is designed for multiple users, etc.

Comment: One benefit is that I have a consistent way of referencing external libs. I will be able to trust that my *packages.config* file gives me an accurate picture of my external dependencies, instead of having to amalgamate what's in *packages.config* and what's in some *Lib* directory.

Answer (score 1):

Project-local NuGet feeds... Where would you want to put that one relative to your projects? And how would you want to share this "local" feed with your team mates? Just wondering, because NuGet already installs all packages project-local ($(SolutionDir)\Packages), so you could as well just disable package restore and commit your packages into VCS?

There might be an alternative: did you try [MyGet.org](http://www.myget.org) already? We offer you NuGet-as-a-Service hosted on Windows Azure: sign-up, create a feed (or more), optionally secure it, invite others and get going. Here's a list of [features](http://www.myget.org/Home/Features) provided on top of the default NuGet server functionality. MyGet also ensures compatibility with the latest NuGet client tools on all our plans, for free.

There's also a free plan and you can get started with a trial on any of the other plans as well. Check http://www.myget.org/plans or send an email for more info. Also check out the enterprise plan if you're looking for integration with on-premise Active Directory for instance.
If you don't want a hosted solution and want to maintain everything yourself, then maybe ProGet is something for you.